# How can I use CreateObject and pass user input when object takes over?

Tags: vba, infopath, infopath2010

Because [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18925065/embedding-infopath-form-in-email-with-vba-using-smtp-cdo) does not appear resolvable, I am exploring a different option for automatically generating an InfoPath email.

The below code works, except once I use `.Submit` it prompts me for using input - basically the InfoPath window requires me to hit "Send" on a dialogue box.

I am hoping there is a way to get basically do what the code below does in pseudo code. The problem is when `.Submit` is called ([documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb229827(v=office.12).aspx) - doesn't look like there's any flag I can pass/set to ignore this), VBA waits for the key presses to continue (so `SendKeys` doesn't work like the below, at least to do Alt+S).

See the following image for an example of a confirmation which appears:

[image]

I want to either suppress this (even if I have to change how I'm creating InfoPath emails) or be able to fake a "Send" keypress.

```
Private Sub GenerateInfoPathEmail()

    Dim mFilePath As String
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim objEmailAdapter As EmailAdapterObject

    mFilePath = "A:\tmp\testform.xsn"
    Set oApp = CreateObject("InfoPath.Application")
    oApp.XDocuments.NewFromSolution (mFilePath)

    'infopath form has a connection called "email"
    Set objEmailAdapter = oApp.XDocuments(0).DataAdapters("email")
    objEmailAdapter.To = "myEmail@myDomain.com"
    objEmailAdapter.CC = ""
    objEmailAdapter.Intro = "intro"
    objEmailAdapter.Subject = "subject"
    objEmailAdapter.AttachmentType = 1 'xdXmlXns
    objEmailAdapter.AttachmentFileName = mFilePath

    'I want to be able to pass through
    'the silly user input here to basically
    'hit "send" (alt+s for keyboard shortcut)
    objEmailAdapter.Submit
    SendKeys ("%s")  ' This obviously won't work because the code waits for user input


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use infopath so can't test the appraoch there, but you may be able to use sendkeys to get around this problem by filling the required fields and using the `{tab}` code (see below). I'm hoping the tab key will move between the fields on the user input form.

A word of caution, sendkeys can be unreliable so it might not be the best idea, but if you can't find another way around the issue it may be worth a try.

```
Sub testSendKeys()
    Dim SendkeyString As String

    Application.Wait (3)                        'Wait 3 seconds to allow 
                                                'form to load
    SendkeyString = "myEmail@myDomain.com"      'Fill in the to field that appears
                                                'to be selected by default
    SendkeyString = SendkeyString & "{tab}"     'Tab to CC field
    SendkeyString = SendkeyString & "{tab}"     'Tab to BCC field
    SendkeyString = SendkeyString & "{tab}"     'Tab to Subject field
    SendkeyString = SendkeyString & "subject"   'Fill in subject details
    SendkeyString = SendkeyString & "%s"        'Alt-S to send

    SendKeys (SendkeyString)
End Sub
```